# Code is not executed in server side?

Tags: c#, web-applications, aforge

The code tested and working in local computer but not in server side. 
So, i use **log4net** to see what happen, and here is what the log4net produce: http://pastebin.com/Xr3iq68t
 As you all can see, i put **log4net** almost in every line of my code.

What is the differences between my local computer with server(i'am using somee.com free hosting to test the code).
If it because of permission problem, i have tested another code which is downloading a snapshot from same source and save it in server side folder and it can save it.
So, is there anything wrong with the code?

The code executed until `Rec` class only, not proceed to the rest of the code. It should go to `video_NewFrame` after that, but from log file record, it not continue.
Complete code can be viewed here: http://pastebin.com/VCjVj3uc

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string usr = "http://IPaddress.com:8081/snapshot.cgi";
    log.Info("DDNS: " + usr);
    log.Info("Starting JPEG stream...");
    //camera source
    JPEGSource = new JPEGStream(usr);
    log.Info("***JPEGSource = new JPEGStream(usr);***");
    JPEGSource.Login = login;
    JPEGSource.Password = password;
    log.Info("***JPEG login & password***");
    JPEGSource.Start();
    log.Info("JPEGSource.Start()");
    JPEGSource.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler( video_NewFrame );
    log.Info("***Goto video_NewFrame class***");

    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(6000);
    //Label2.Text = Label2.Text + streamingSource + "<br> "; 
    this.Label1.Text = "Camera Source: " + usr;
}

private void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
   Bitmap image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
   log.Info("***Bitmap image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();***");
   width = image.Width;
   height = image.Height;

   frames.Enqueue((Bitmap)image.Clone());
   log.Info("***Cloning frame***");

   if (!IsRecording)
   {
       log.Info("Entering thread");
       IsRecording = true;
       Thread th = new Thread(DoRecording);
       th.Start();
   }
}
```

Note: camera Ip address is DDNS ip address.

Comment: the only thing I see is that could possibly be causing this is that your page class instance dies after each request:) so nobody's there to listen to the events (which unluckily but may be leaking memory) taking with it the `JPEGStream` variable. Pages in ISS are not good for this type of tasks which require for the object to hang around a little longer.

Comment: it maybe working locally in debug mode in Visual Studio because the webdev server executes the requests in single threads and could actually give you the illusion that it's working ok. Have you tried to deploy it on a local IIS (not when debugging in VS) to see if it works ?

Comment: @user1416420 I deployed my code in local IIS and i got this error `an unhandled microsoft .net framework exception occurred in w3wp.exe` which is related to leaking memory problem just like u said. For debug mode, its not an illusion, its actually work where i got the actual output from the code(video successfully recorded and saved in folder). Still searching how solve this problem..

Comment: @user1416420 `an unhandled microsoft .net framework exception occurred in w3wp.exe` problem caused by read/write permission because after i change and allow the permission for read/write, the error not shown anymore. But in server side case, the folder permission is set to read/write, but how could it not writing/creating file? And how can i handle the error and document it in log file instead?

Comment: @user1416420 I still cannot solve this problem, do u have suggestion?